# How can I conduct research when my college has no such facility?

Tags: graduate-admissions, research-process, research-assistantship

In developing countries like Nepal, people don't usually carry research activities during undergrad studies, but I want to get into it from undergrad itself. I am currently studying research articles, consulting professors and will be contacting governement research organisation to ask for support for devices required.

Answer (score 9):

Since you specified Nepal, I'd like to make a suggestion - there are some excellent research institutes in India where you can apply to be a 'Junior Research Fellow' after completing your Bachelor's. You won't get a degree, but you will get a modest stipend and the chance to boost your research profile.

I had some friends from Nepal during my undergraduate studies, and a few of them applied to these places, got selected, and after a year and a half of doing research there, went on to top-notch European and American institutes to do graduate studies. I hope you look into it. Good luck!

Comment: Is there any way where I can take my studies and research parallel ?

Comment: And certified experience is a must?

Comment: I think you would need to be a student enrolled in one of the Indian institutes to study and do research simultaneously, unless there is an option to do research remotely - but you should definitely contact faculty in the IITs and IISc for more options! Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I've never heard of any US university requiring an "experience certificate". I don't even know what that would mean.  There's certainly no organized system for "certifying" such things.

If you have had research experience that is relevant to your field, you can write about it in your statement of purpose, and get letters of  recommendation from people familiar with your work, and universities will take it into account.

Comment: Will it be appropriate for undergrad level lab experience if I get involved in Neurobiology research which I will be pursuing in my Graduate university rather than getting involved in Computer science related research at present?

Comment: And this would obviously be different thing than my field since I'm a CS student but I would wish to do it for the sake of knowledge I will be needing in my Grad university. Will it be a wise idea or I should just stick to CS research?

Comment: In general, research experience in a field closer to the program where you are applying will be more valuable.

Comment: @ManishYadav: You should keep in mind, of course, that admission to places like MIT is ridiculously competitive, and that many extremely qualified applicants still get rejected.  It's not a good idea to plan your entire life around getting into MIT - make sure you have lots of alternative plans.  If this research fits into those plans also, great, but don't do it solely as a route to MIT.